# Бот для игры в Flash Player на Python

Tags: python, flash, бот

Есть онлайн игра во Флэш Плеере, играют в нее через окно браузера.
Игра простая  - в зависимости от картинок нужно нажимать на соответствующие кнопки, без всяких сложных движений мышкой и вообще без клавиатуры. 
Мне нужно написать для нее бота на Python (знаю только его). Раньше я такого никогда не делал, поэтому мне виднеется один вариант: сделать скриншоты всех необходимых картинок из игры в соответствующих координатах, для этого использовать pyscreenshot; написать код для собственно игры; с помощью autopy двигать мышкой и кликать в необходимые места.

Вопрос: это нормальный подход? Возможный?

Или пробовать другие варианты, пытаться найти API этой игры или каким еще образом пишут подобных ботов?

Игра онлайн, там участвуют другие игроки, какие либо вмешательства сайт заметит 100%, а вариант со скриншотами можно запалить (в смысле использования бота) только по "нечеловеческим" движениям мышки. Но это можно легко обойти, дописав рандомные движения.

Итак, рабочий ли это подход? Может у кого есть информация\гайд про такое?

Comment: Я как-то не понял, можете объяснить попроще, что будет бот делать?

Comment: Играть в игру, используя скриншоты  из нее

Answer (score 1):

С ботами для флеш игр надо малость покопаться. Насчёт Phyton ничего не могу сказать - это специфичный язык. Но можно написать бота написать бота на ActionScript .

Внутри флеш-приложения, все анимационные элементы и кнопки организованы в дерево элементов. Оно весьма похоже на DOM дерево в web-странице: по признакам можно легко найти любой элемент в дереве, например кнопку; можно узнать какого цвета кнопка, видима ли она; можно легко узнать её координаты. Доступ ко флеш приложению из стророннего приложения можно получить через **PreloadSwf**.

Суть такова - вы устанавливаете **флеш debug версии** , [в папку пользователя windows добавляете конфиг mm.cfg](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html) . В конфиг прописываете параметр:

```
PreloadSwf=C:/путькswf/PreloadSwf.swf
```

И перед загрузкой абсолютно любой флешки в браузере, например: загрузится PreloadSwf.swf . И он будет иметь полный доступ к приложению: сможет перебирать дерево элементов, сможет эмулировать щелчки или нажатия клавиш.

Соответственно PreloadSwf вы пишете сами, внутри перед загрузкой проверяете по формальным параметрам вроде названия: та ли это игра. Если да - запускаете бота.

На том же принципе preloadswf основан популярный плагин для отладки **flashfirebug**

Answer (score 1):

Распозновать картинки поможет компьютерное зрение `cv2`
 Кликать по ним мышкой поможет `pyautogui`

Comment: `pyautogui` как раз и может искать и кликать на экране, для поиска используя картинки